# Not able to append to an empty container map in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to write a function that divides a matrix based on its 'class value'. For example, if we say that the 'class' of a vector input is the value in the last column, I want to split a matrix like

```
[1 2 1; ...
3 4 0; ...
1 3 1; ...
6 7 2; ...
6 7 0; ...
6 7 1]
```

as (based on the value of the last column)

```
(Class 1)
[1 2 1; ...
1 3 1; ...
6 7 1]

and 

(Class 0)
[3 4 0; ...
6 7 0]

and

(Class 2)

[6 7 2]
```

I want to have a format as close as possible to a Python dictionary, and so I opted for a container map. But I'm having some issues with the key type of the container map.

This is the function I have written.

```
function [separated] = separateByClass(dataset)
    % assume the class variable is the last column of the dataset
    % We return a container map mapping the unique class variables to the
    % row instances from the dataset

    separated = containers.Map;  % setting up the container map

    for i=1:size(dataset, 1)
        vector = dataset(i, :);
        class_var = vector(end);
        if isKey(separated, class_var)== 0
            separated(class_var) = vector;
        else
            separated(class_var) = [separated(class_var); vector];
        end
    end

end
```

I get an error message on the line `separated(class_var) = vector;` during the first iteration of the loop.

```
Error using containers.Map/subsasgn
Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.

Error in separateByClass (line 12)
            separated(class_var) = vector;
```

I don't if the issue is that I'm adding to an empty container map, and so key types don't match?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the default type that a container map sets as per -
https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html

Just had to change the keyType and valueType to 'any', and that allowed handling of double-type keys and matrix values!

Comment: If you set the type to ‘double’ you’ll get a more efficient container. The ‘any’ type is not efficient.